# Get the number of likes via Facebook API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm using Facebook's graph API to get the number of likes for several pages on my website. I'm sending a GET request like so:

http://graph.facebook.com/?ids=http://example.com/1

For some pages, the number of returned likes is correct (they are called "shares" for some reason, why?), but for other pages the number is incorrect. Is that a Facebook bug? Is there another way to get the number of likes? I tried with FQL, but had no luck there, and besides I read that it's deprecated.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide some examples of URLs and how many "likes" you expect them to have?

Comment: Certainly. Here's an  example with a real URL: http://graph.facebook.com/?ids=http://www.respirated.com/brands/3m-1.html                                                                                                                             If you visit the page you will see that it has 1 like, though the API returns 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, apparently the object that you are getting when you try the example URL is a Graph URL object:  https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/url

The object you are getting when you try the real URL is a Graph Page object.

URL objects were added in Graph API v2.1, so technically you shouldn't really ever get a URL object when using an unversioned facebook request (since it defaults to v2.0).  If you specify a Graph version of 2.1 or greater, the real URL will return a URL object with the correct number of likes (shares).

Try this:
`https://graph.facebook.com/v2.3?ids=http://www.respirated.com/brands/3m-1.html&access_token=<access token>`

Using a specific version does seem to require an access token.  That might make your solution more complex if you weren't already using access tokens...